# Network configuration for Virtual machine based firewall

Tags: firewall, virtualbox, pfsense

I have this physical configuration:

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img537/7803/tUyDRw.png]

And I'm planning to install IPFire (or similar firewall : pfSense or Sophos UTM) on a virtual machine on the Active Directory Server to control traffic between the internal 192.168.1.0/24 network (including AD Server) and the internet.

What is the appropriate configuration on the AD Server and the VM?

**Edit based on [Dan](https://serverfault.com/users/95832/dan)'s comment:** This is planned for a production environment.
How about if install both AD and Firewall on virtual machines running on the physical server (Windows Server installed)?

Comment: Jalil - is this a production, professional network? If so, installing VirtualBox onto your Domain Controller is an awful idea. At the very least, your AD server should be a proper virtualisation solution with both a virtualised firewall and a virtual DC. VirtualBox is not suitable for a production environment. If not, then this question is off-topic.

Comment: You can use 2 vms fine, but don't use VirtualBox or the like. Use either Hyper-V, ESXi or similar virtualization software.